# For loop to add numbers and get Average inside Text Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**SCENARIO**

I am getting the json data by using `flutter_bloc` library pattern what i want to achieve is that i want to count/add the `star` key numbers and divide by length of `star` means get the average number of stars. Below is the json data and dart code till now what i did.

> JSON Data

```
"feedbacks": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "comment": "Corporate Brand Supervisor",
                    "star": 1,
                    "createdAt": "2021-09-07T11:35:15.954Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-09-07T11:35:15.954Z",
                    "customerId": 10,
                    "branchId": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "comment": "Principal Implementation Liaison",
                    "star": 1,
                    "createdAt": "2021-09-07T11:35:15.954Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-09-07T11:35:15.954Z",
                    "customerId": 1,
                    "branchId": 3
                }
            ],
```

> HomePage.dart

```
Row(
children: [
for (var i in data[index].feedbacks!)
Text(i!.star!.toString()),],), //Here expecting an average number of stars 1+1/2 = 1.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only display the result (average) value of stars in a `Text` widget, you can do this:

```dart
Text((data[index]['feedbacks']!.map<int>((feedback) => feedback['star'] as int).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr) / data[index]['feedbacks']!.length).toStringAsFixed(2))
```

This assumes that every entry in `feedback` actually has a `star` property since I'm dividing by the amount of entries in `feedback`

I also added `toStringAsFixed(2)` to ensure that there a 2 decimals after the decimal point (might want to adjust that) instead of having a very long value in cases like 1/3